# How to create ASMX with refreshed data

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I have a web service(ASMX) which generates JSON data. What I want to do is update this generated JSON page depends on the any changes happened on SQL database via sqldependency.
(I am planing to get those data from my Android phone making requests for  every 3 second..)

I searched on the Net but couldn't find an appropriate solution. How can I achieve that? I am open to any solution to achieve that. Is there any other solution to do that, like for instance create a static JSON page and update this or another solution.

Comment: Please provide the code for your ASMX. We can't `update` what we don't have an original copy of.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Of course, ASMX still functions and sakir may not need the full overhead of implementing WCF or Web API.

Comment: I just read your article,it contains  usefull info.thank u .asmx is easy to implement for not big project